# Loop over list and increment with values to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested-lists

I have a list of this format:

```
some_list = [[-5, 1000], 
           [0, 600], 
           [50, 600],
           [100,700],
           [170,650],
           [190,700]]
```

and the function return should be a resulting dict with keys -5, -4, -3 ... and with values as the sum of increments up to each key. so for example above should be -5 : 0 , -4 : 1000, -3 : 2000, -1 : 3000, 0 : 4000, 1 : 4600 and onwards.

Here is some code which is partly working. The problem is the while statement which needs a ceiling to check against and I've therefore added additional items at the end of the list. Assume this can be solved in a much more elegant way. Also the current code exclude last item row of the list due to the break statement.

```
def framegen(some_list):
    n = 0
    ys = some_list[0][0] 
    frame = []
    xpos = []
    x2 = 0
    for i in some_list:
        while (some_list[n][0]) <= ys < (some_list[(n+1)][0]):
            x1 = ys
            frame.append(x1)
            xpos.append(x2)
            x2 += some_list[n][1]                 
            ys += 1                
            if n == len(some_list) -2 :
                break
        else:
            n += 1        
    temp_dic = dict(zip(frame, xpos))
    dic = {}
    for n in temp_dic:
        dic[n] = temp_dic[n] - temp_dic[0]
    return dic
```

Edit:

expected output:

```
   { -5 : 0 , 
-4 : 1000 , 
-3 : 2000 , 
-2 : 3000 , 
-1 : 4000 , 
0 : 5000 , 
1 : 5600 , 
2 : 6200 ,
....}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want in the resulting dict. Please [edit] your question and show what the desired result would be for the same input.

Comment: Edited expected output. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how the expected output is calculated? It's not quite clear.

Comment: The first item in the list is the "counter" while the last item is the multiplier. So from -15 to 0, each step of 1 shall be incrementedd with 1000. From 0 to 100 the increment for each step of 1 is 600, and so forth. Last item increment should probably been given None as value as it is not used. The resulting dictionary should stop at last item in list which is 190.

Comment: The `....}` at the end of your expected output indicates it's there's more not being shown. When does it stop?

Comment: it stops at 190. Now got the added code to work, but the break leads to that the last item row in list is not processed. It therefore now stops at 171. Also an issue with my code is that if the input list only have 2 rows the code will not run.

Comment: Working code now edited in for further info. Again thanks for assistance

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows, iterating over each interval and filling the dictionary based on the previous value.

**Code:**

```
some_list = [[-5, 1000], 
           [0, 600], 
           [50, 600],
           [100,700],
           [170,650],
           [190,700]]

d = dict()

for s, e in zip(some_list[:-1], some_list[1:]):
    for k in range(s[0], e[0] + 1):
        if k not in d:
            d[k] = d.get(k-1, -s[1]) + s[1]
```

**Output**

```
>>> d
{-5: 0,
 -4: 1000,
 -3: 2000,
 -2: 3000,
 -1: 4000,
 0: 5000,
 1: 5600,
 2: 6200,
 3: 6800,
 4: 7400,
 ...
 181: 121150,
 182: 121800,
 183: 122450,
 184: 123100,
 185: 123750,
 186: 124400,
 187: 125050,
 188: 125700,
 189: 126350,
 190: 127000}
```